# How does spring sso authentication with oauth2 work?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I've set up 2 oauth2 client Spring Boot 2 web applications running on different ports and an authorization server.  If I authenticate on one web application, I can then go and access a secured resource on the other. Brilliant, SSO in action!

But looking at the network traffic, I can't see any Bearer tokens on headers, only some SESSIONID related cookies.  The use of HTTP sessions got me worrying that horizontal scaling could be an issue.  Then I realized that the second application is working and authenticating somehow.

So what is the browser passing on the call to the 2nd web application that enables it to use the existing authentication? Are there any scaling concerns due to the use of http session by spring security.

thanks

ui oauth2 client application.yml (using spring boot 2 security's oauth2 client implementation)

```
spring:
  profiles: oauth2-security
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          myoauth:
            client-id: myoauth-trusted-client
            client-secret: ...
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri-template: http://localhost:${server.port}/ui/login/oauth2/code/myoauth
        provider:
          myoauth:
            authorization-uri: http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/token
            user-info-uri: http://localhost:8081/auth/user_info
            user-info-authentication-method: header
            user-name-attribute: name
```

The authz server. using the shim jar spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthorizationServerConfig(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager) //for use with password grant type
                .authorizationCodeServices(new InMemoryAuthorizationCodeServices()); //for use with authorization_code grant type
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("myoauth-trusted-client")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                    .secret("{bcrypt}" + new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("..."))
                    .scopes("all")
                    .autoApprove(true)
                    .redirectUris("http://localhost:8082/ui/login/oauth2/code/myoauth", "http://localhost:8083/ui/login/oauth2/code/myoauth").and()
                .withClient("myoauth-client-with-secret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "client_credentials")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                    .scopes("read")
                    .secret("{bcrypt}" + new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("..."))
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your Spring Security configurations for all three applications.

Comment: done, the two client applications are the same code base running on different ports. Whilst this is working well, I wonder how it will work with non-spring clients, hence the question really.